# ViewModel MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC. I am going through the following
[tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript).

I am on the portion where it calls for the following code

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit(UserModel um) 
{

  if (!TryUpdateModel(um)) 
  {
    ViewModel.updateError = "Update Failure";
    return View(um);
  }

  // ToDo: add persistent to DB.
  _usrs.Update(um);
  return View("Details", um);
}
```

When I attempt to use ViewModel I receive an error:

"The name ViewModel does not exist in the current context."

Intellisense does not show ViewModel as an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ViewModel does not exist for a mvc 3 controller. I think what you are looking to use instead is the following:

```
ViewBag.UpdateError = "Update Failure";
```

Then in your view:

```
@View.UpdateError
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit late, but it may be better practice to use the following:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Update Failure");
```

Then, in your view:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
ViewModel.UpdateError = "Update Failure";

Use

**ViewBag.UpdateError** = "Update Failure";

And In your View, Use this

**@ViewBag.UpdateError**